# Python timezones - pytz.common_timezones has too many

Tags: python, timezone

There are way too many overlapping timezones in pytz's common list. Has anyone pared this down? For example there are 5 or 6 duplicate Canadian timezones and 15 or so duplicate US time zones. China is 1 timezone no DST, but has 5 entries.. By duplicate I mean GMT offset and DST are exactly the same.

Getting rid of the timezones in pytz.country_timezones['us'] gets rid of the duplicate US timezones as it only contains the America/* zones and not the base US/* zones. This doesn't work for other countries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's a good idea. In Australia, Melbourne and Sydney usually share the same timezone, however the choice of when DST starts and ends is controlled by two different bodies.

When Melbourne hosted the Commonwealth Games a few years back, they changed the DST (just for the one year) for convenience. I think Sydney may have changed also to avoid confusion, but they did have to decide that separately from Melbourne.

Comment: There are still obvious duplicates with same DST that I know for sure such as the US ones and Chinese ones. None of the python timezone recommendations on this site are any good, was hoping at least if pytz's common zones were narrowed it'd be useful.

Comment: And with Australia/Brisbane, there is no DST, so the distinction is even more important.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of deprecated timezones:
https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/a11229c46f79ed377ff8e1006ccb98b1b38c4ad0/tz/backward

Although, looks like that list is missing some duplicate timezones.

Thirteen timezones in `pytz.common_timezones` are deprecated from that list:

```
[
    'Canada/Atlantic',
    'Canada/Central',
    'Canada/Eastern',
    'Canada/Mountain',
    'Canada/Newfoundland',
    'Canada/Pacific',
    'US/Alaska',
    'US/Arizona',
    'US/Central',
    'US/Eastern',
    'US/Hawaii',
    'US/Mountain',
    'US/Pacific',
]
```